# With Http and arbitrary loader true. Can I upload app to App Store?

Tags: ios, https, appstore-approval

I know its not an bit technical question. But I still did not get any expert help to go on to this issues. So I am posting here.

I know  `arbitrary loader = yes` is mandatory from 2018. But with my `http` and `arbitrary loader = yes` will they allow my app to app store.

Is it `arbitrary loader = yes` is mandatory when we push to app store. Because my application have only http with some port number db for api call . should I need to do https or with http i can upload to app store.

With `http` and `arbitrary loader = no`.it not even running in my simulator and device

So please confirm if i set `arbitrary loader=yes`, with http call will apple approve my app OR should i needs to use only https and `arbitrary loader = yes`.

Please suggest some idea for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the security reason Apple doesn't allow the`http` api call to the app. You need to either call`https` api or you can by pass this by settings `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` in Info.plist file.

If you upload app on App Store apple with `http` with `Allow Arbitrary Loads` set to `YES` then they won't reject you app for this reason at least.

So feel free to submit your app to App Store.

If you use `https` api call then no need to worry about anything.

Note: you can also add exception domains in Info.plist.